# Is there any way to shorten the followning code?

Tags: sql, join, subquery

> Question: Write a query to display the name of the departments that has the least student count. Sort the result based on department name in ascending order

My Code:

```sql
select department_name
     from department d join student s
     on d.department_id=s.department_id
     having count(*) in (select min(count(student_id))
                         from student s join department d
                         on s.department_id=d.department_id
                         group by d.department_id)
group by department_name
order by department_name;
```

Note:
`Student`, `Department` are separate tables
`department_id` is Primary key in `Department` Table
`department_id` is ForeignKey in `Student` Table
Code works perfectly (just need to shorten this).

Comment: hi, there's no need for that image, you can format code, just indent it with 4 spaces and it turns into code

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I don't believe the code works perfectly because it's invalid (standard) SQL - `having` needs to come after `group by`

Answer (score 0):

I would use a window function for that:

```
select d.*
from (
  select s.department_id, 
         count(*) as student_count,
         dense_rank() over (order by count(*)) as rnk
  from student s 
  group by s.department_id
) as c
  join department d on d.department_id = c.department_id 
where c.rnk = 1
order by d.department_name;
```

If you want, you can also include the actual student count in the output.

---

The above only includes departments that do have students. If you need to take care of departments that have no students assigned, you need an outer join:

```
select d.department_name
from (
  select d.department_name,
         count(s.student_id)  as student_count, 
         dense_rank() over (order by count(s.student_id)) as rnk
  from department d 
    left join student s on s.department_id = d.department_id
  group by d.department_name
) d
where d.rnk = 1;
```

Both solutions are 100% standard ANSI SQL and should work on any modern DBMS.